# Erase Part of Bitmap with another Bitmap

Tags: c#, image, winforms, alpha, erase

Let me preface this with a real life product; You may remember in Elementary school, they had scratch paper which basically consisted of a rainbow-colored sheet of paper with a black film on top. You would take a sharp object and peel away the black film to expose the colored paper.

I am attempting to do the same thing using images in a picture box.

My idea consists of these things:

- A textured image.
- A black rectangle the size of the picture box.
- A circle image.

What I am trying to achieve is to open a program, have an image drawn to a picture box with the black rectangle on top of it. Upon clicking the picture box it uses the circle to invert the alpha of the rectangle where I click using the circle as a reference.

- My Problem-
  I cannot figure out any way to erase (set the transparency of) a part of the black rectangle where I click.

For the life of me, I do not know of any method to cut a window in an image. It is almost like a reverse crop, where I keep the exterior elements rather than the interior, exposing the textured image below.

Can WinForms not do this? Am I crazy? Should I just give up?

I should mention that I prefer not to have to change alpha on a pixel per pixel basis. It would slow the program down far too much to be used as a pseudo-painter. If that is the only way, however, feel free to show.

Here is an image of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Windows Forms is probably not going to help you implement this, though you can always custom draw a control.  WPF may give you better tools for the job, though I'm not sure about this specific task.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not really hard:

- Set the colored image as a `PictureBox`'s `BackgroundImage`.
- Set a black image as its `Image`.
- And draw into the image using the normal mouse events and a transparent `Pen`..

[image]

We need a point list to use `DrawCurve`:

```
List<Point> currentLine = new List<Point>();
```

We need to prepare and clear the the black layer:

```
private void ClearSheet()
{
    if (pictureBox1.Image != null) pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width, pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height);
    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) G.Clear(Color.Black);
    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
    currentLine.Clear();
}

private void cb_clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClearSheet();
}
```

To draw into the `Image` we need to use an associated `Graphics` object..:

```
void drawIntoImage()
{
    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
    {
        // we want the tranparency to copy over the black pixels
        G.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
        G.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        G.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

        using (Pen somePen = new Pen(Color.Transparent, penWidth))
        {
            somePen.MiterLimit = penWidth / 2;
            somePen.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;
            somePen.LineJoin = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineJoin.Round;
            somePen.StartCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;
            if (currentLine.Count > 1)
                G.DrawCurve(somePen, currentLine.ToArray());
        }

    }
    // enforce the display:
    pictureBox1.Image = pictureBox1.Image;
}
```

The usual mouse events:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    currentLine.Add(e.Location);
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        currentLine.Add(e.Location);
        drawIntoImage();
    }  
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    currentLine.Clear();
}
```

That's all that's needed. Make sure to keep the PB's `SizeMode = Normal` or else the pixels won't match..!

Note that there are a few challenges when you want to get soft edges, more painting tools, letting a simple click paint a dot or an undo or other finer details to work. But the basics are not hard at all..

Btw, changing `Alpha` is not **any** different from changing the color channels.

As an alternative you may want to play with a `TextureBrush`:

```
TextureBrush brush = new TextureBrush(pictureBox1.BackgroundImage);

using (Pen somePen = new Pen(brush) )
{
  // basically 
  // the same drawing code.. 
}
```

But I found this to be rather slow.

**Update:**

Using a `png`-file as a custom tip is a little harder; the main reason is that the drawing is reversed: We don't want to draw the pixels, we want to clear them. `GDI+` doesn't support any such composition modes, so we need to do it in code.

To be fast we use two tricks: `LockBits` will be as fast as it gets and restricting the area to our custom brush tip will prevent wasting time.

Let's assume you have a file to use and load it into a bitmap:

```
string stampFile = @"yourStampFile.png";
Bitmap stamp = null;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    stamp = (Bitmap) Bitmap.FromFile(stampFile);
}
```

Now we need a new function to draw it into our `Image`; instead of `DrawCurve` we need to use `DrawImage`:

```
void stampIntoImage(Point pt)
{
    Point point =  new Point(pt.X - stamp.Width / 2, pt.Y - stamp.Height / 2);
    using (Bitmap stamped = new Bitmap(stamp.Width, stamp.Height) )
    {
        using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(stamped))
        {
            stamp.SetResolution(stamped.HorizontalResolution, stamped.VerticalResolution);
            G.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceOver;
            G.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, 0, 0, 
                        new Rectangle(point, stamped.Size), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            writeAlpha(stamped, stamp);
        }
        using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
        {
            G.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
            G.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            G.CompositingQuality = 
               System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            G.DrawImage(stamped, point);
        }
    }
    pictureBox1.Image = pictureBox1.Image;
}
```

A few notes: I found that I hat to do an explicit `SetResolution` since the stamp file I photoshopped was `72dpi` and the default Bitmaps in my program were `120dpi`. Watch out for these differences!

I start the Bitmap to be drawn by **copying** the right part of the **current** Image.

Then I call a fast routine that applies the alpha of the stamp to it:

```
void writeAlpha(Bitmap target, Bitmap source)
{
   // this method assumes the bitmaps both are 32bpp and have the same size
    int Bpp = 4;  
    var bmpData0 = target.LockBits(
                    new Rectangle(0, 0, target.Width, target.Height),
                    ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, target.PixelFormat);
    var bmpData1 = source.LockBits(
                    new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height),
                    ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, source.PixelFormat);

    int len = bmpData0.Height * bmpData0.Stride;
    byte[] data0 = new byte[len];
    byte[] data1 = new byte[len];
    Marshal.Copy(bmpData0.Scan0, data0, 0, len);
    Marshal.Copy(bmpData1.Scan0, data1, 0, len);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += Bpp)
    {
        int tgtA = data0[i+3];        // opacity
        int srcA = 255 - data1[i+3];  // transparency
        if (srcA > 0) data0[i + 3] = (byte)(tgtA < srcA ? 0 : tgtA - srcA);
    }
    Marshal.Copy(data0, 0, bmpData0.Scan0, len);
    target.UnlockBits(bmpData0);
    source.UnlockBits(bmpData1);
}
```

I use a simple rule: Reduce target opacity by the source transparency and make sure we don't get negative.. You may want to play around with it.

Now all we need is to adapt the `MouseMove`; for my tests I have added two `RadioButtons` to switch between the original round pen and the custom stamp tip:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        if (rb_pen.Checked)
        {
            currentLine.Add(e.Location);
            drawIntoImage();
        }
        else if (rb_stamp.Checked) { stampIntoImage(e.Location); };
    }
}
```

I didn't use a fish but you can see the soft edges:

[image]

**Update 2**: Here is a `MouseDown` that allows for simple clicks:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if (rb_pen.Checked) currentLine.Add(e.Location);
   else if (rb_stamp.Checked)
   {
       { stampIntoImage(e.Location); };
   }
}
```

Comment: This is just about everything I was looking for with one exception. Is there a way to use a PNG image as a "brush tip"? For example, use a fish-shaped brush to cut away instead of a round-pen. I would settle for it just to be a single cut-out per click of the mouse.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks a lot for the help. I could hug you right now.